# How to play against an engine using Babaschess

Tags: engines, babaschess

I want to play against the computer using some engine with the [Babaschess](http://www.babaschess.net/) program (most used interface program in FICS). I want different levels of strength if possible.
[In this link](https://www.redhotpawn.com/forum/only-chess/play-chess-engine-on-babaschess-4-0.75881) they talk about the possibility but not what I need: